# Why did it take chrome performance system time so long？

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I listened for the mouse wheel event in the code and executed a rendering of WebGL each time the wheel event was triggered. However, there was one problem that could not be solved: when scrolling, frames were often lost.

I'm making a map app, and the mouse scroll triggers the map to zoom in and out.

```
// Render function call:
public requestRender() {
    if (!this._waitingRender) {
        this._waitingRender = requestAnimationFrame(
            this._renderFrame.bind(this),
        );
    }
}

// Render function defined
    private _renderFrame() {
        if (!this._styleLoaded) {
            cancelAnimationFrame((this._waitingRender = 0));
            this._waitingRender = 0;
            return;
        }
        const frameState = this._getState();
        this._sourceManager.loadData(
            frameState.viewState,
            this,
            this._mapRender.context,
        );
        this._mapRender.renderFrame(frameState);
        this._waitingRender = 0;
        this._diffState();
        return;
    }
```

This is my performance:
[image]

Comment: I dont know what you  mean with "frames were lost", but I guess it has to do with how mousescroll works. the event fires an action multiple times each scroll. If you do some heavy work on every action, it will be too much load and it will skip some iterations.

Comment: Sorry，"frames were lost" means the frame is not 60fps. My English is not well.

Comment: Yeah, so you have your explanation above. If the load is too heavy to calculate 60 frames every second, it will just do as many as possible. Either make the calculations less impacting, or use a stronger hardware.

Comment: I found that the timeline was blank, but the CPU load was so heavy that I didn't know what the CPU was doing, so I didn't know how to optimize the code